# Extra pieces in a lot, not sure what to do with them

Tags: sets

All right so I bought a couple Lego sets of the garage sale all the pieces are there but there's so many extra pieces and they're not just random The pieces that go to these sets is there anyway that you can look up with using a database of some kind to figure out what set all these pieces go to I h

Comment: You h what? Looks like something might be missing from the end of your question.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is. However, it requires two pieces of knowledge:

1. You need to understand how [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com) or [BrickSet](https://www.brickset.com) categorize the 10,000+ types of LEGO bricks in existence. This means knowing the difference between a Brick, a Plate and a Tile, understanding the various Modified versions of these basic types etc.
2. You need to be able to identify pieces in your stash of bricks that are special or not commonly used. The best candidates are bricks with stickers, as stickers are often special to just one set.

Once you have identified one or more unique pieces, look them up and see which sets they came in. Look through the inventory of those sets to confirm you have most of the other pieces in that set as well, and voila: you have found your set.
Next, go to www.lego.com and download the instruction manual for that set, then build the set to verify its completeness.

Note: if one of the stickered pieces contains a car license plate, or any other sticker with a 4 or 5 digit number on it, chances are that that is the set number. Then just validate that other pieces from this set are also in your pile of bricks.

Comment: You can skip trying to search through tiles and modified plates etc if you just look for the little code under each piece. 4-5 tiny numbers you can type into either site and find the piece straight away.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of really good sites which list the parts in sets. [BrickLink.com](http://BrickLink.com) and [BrickSet.com](https://BrickSet.com) are the two I use the most.